# What is a better practice, to combine two interfaces through extension, or to cast an interface to its implementing type?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

Let's say that I have two interfaces and a behavior class:

```
public interface Creable {
    public boolean belongsToSystem();
    public List<Creable> getCreatedItems();
}

public interface HasDependencies {
    public void createDependencies();
    public void generateDependents();
}

public class CreableBehavior {
    private Creable creableObject;
    public CreableBehavior(Creable creableObject) {
         this.creableObject = creableObject;
    }

    public boolean hasBeenCreated() {
        return !creableObject.belongsToSystem() && !creableObject.getCreatedItems().contains(createdObject);
    }
```

And this piece of code:

```
Creable includedTab = new AdempiereTab(getIncluded_Tab_ID(),
                creableElements);
if (!new CreableBehavior(includedTab).hasBeenCreated) {
    includedTab.createDependencies();
    includedTab.getCreatedItems().add(includedTab);
    includedTab.generateDependents();
}
```

AdempiereTab implements both Creable and HasDependencies. The problem is that I need to use both interfaces Creable and HasDependencies.
Should I cast it like this:

```
if (!new CreableBehavior(includedTab).hasBeenCreated) {
    ((AdempiereTab)includedTab).createDependencies();
    includedTab.getCreatedItems().add(includedTab);
    ((AdempiereTab)includedTab).generateDependents();
}
```

Or should should I create a new interface CreableWithDependencies that extends both interfaces and use that one instead?

Thanks.

EDIT: Answered, I should extend the interface since I don't want to depend on the implementing type. Combining them would allow me to use many types with the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two design forces at work: **Keeping your interfaces as small as possible and minimizing the number of interfaces**.  In general, large interfaces are more problematic to refactor later.

If your interfaces are already used throughout the system, you could split your client code into separate methods or classes, create an interface `CreableHasDependencies` that extends both interfaces, or just use the class type directly.

If this is the first time you are using the interfaces then combine them because interfaces belong to the client code.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about by combining them, but I was afraid it would just make the codebase messier. Thanks.

Comment: There are two design forces at work: Keeping your interfaces as small as possible and minimizing the number of interfaces.  In general, large interfaces are more problematic to refactor later.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the statement "minimizing the number of interfaces". Won't it violate the SOLID principles?  I'm sorry I'm new at static-typed languages.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought based solely on the viewing the code snippet where you create AdempiereTab is that you could simply declare its variable type to be AdempierTab rather than Creable.  You don't need to use the abstract type Creable since you are already aware that this is the type upon which you will execute the interface methods.

Second thought, even though you know that Creable is AdempiereTab (from the previous code lines), it is best practice to check using instanceof before casting to avoid any exceptions.  This substantiates the fact that you should just declare "includedTab" to be AdempiereTab.

Further however, without knowing too much of the context of your application, I do question the interface HasDependencies.  Purely based on the name, it seems to be more of a method in and of itself.  But the behavior it exposes seems to be confusing: create and generate which both return void.  To me, this just begs the question of whether this interface was well thought out and perhaps needs to be reworked into something clearer.  This might help you avoid the problem you are facing right now.

Comment: createDependencies() creates objects which the current object might depend. For example, createDependencies() on AdempiereTab would create a window. generateDependents() should create objects that will depend on this one. On the case of AdempiereTab, that would be AdempiereField's.

What suggestions do you have to improve it?

Comment: My write up focused on naming, which to me is very important when creating an API (interface) for clients.  So, based on your explanation, I would think HasDependencies would be better described with a name like DependencyProvider or DependencyCreator or something along the lines of "I am an object that can create, generate, and return the necessary dependencies that you expect."  I was encouraging an improvement on the name, and description of this interface's purpose, in order to prove its existence.  Otherwise, as I suggested, perhaps the design could be reworked.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do something like this:

```
AdempiereTab includedTab = new AdempiereTab(getIncluded_Tab_ID(),
                creableElements);
if (!new CreableBehavior(includedTab).hasBeenCreated) {
    includedTab.createDependencies();
    creableElements.getCreatedItems.add(includedTab);
    includedTab.generateDependents();
}
```

Since `AdempiereTab` implements both interfaces you can passed `AdempiereTab` to `CreableBehavior's` constructor.

Comment: I'd like to abstract the createDependencies(), add(), generateDependents() cycle for many types. It should work for AdempiereTab, for AdempiereTable, AdempiereWindow, etc... You see how it goes. I need them to share a common interface so the code can work for all of them.